# mail smtp host with Java

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am sending an email using this Java Class from a Linode Server. The curious thing is that I receive the email in my account nunito@gmail.com but not in nunito@domainCompanynameA.com

```
          String from = "info@domainCompanynameB.com";

          // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
          String host = "localhost";

          // Get system properties
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          try{
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("Alert from LINODE");

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText(msg);

             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);

             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I've changed it to

```
public class MailClient {

    protected static final Logger looger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public MailClient(JavaMailSender mailSender, MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.mailContentBuilder = mailContentBuilder;
    }

    //TODO: in a properties
    public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom("info@domainCompanynameB.com");
            messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
            messageHelper.setSubject("Sample mail subject");
            String content = mailContentBuilder.build(message);
            messageHelper.setText(content, true);
        };
        try {
            if (looger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                looger.debug("sending email to " + recipient);
            }
            mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            looger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

But I got the same problem

Comment: Why is that curious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically if you get one email not the other than it is not your sender software that has problem. This issue is highly related to your `mail.smtp.host` server or `domainCompanynameA.com`.

Since `mail.smtp.host` can send some thing to `gmail`. I suspect `domainCompanynameA.com` has blocked your `mail.smtp.host` for various reasons.

One way to solve this is to white list your `mail.smtp.host` at `domainCompanynameA.com`.

Else it requires investigation to locate where the exact problem comes from.

I would highly recommend using 3rd part email api service, hence they are trusted and maintained.